# Scale imageview on tablet with original aspect

Tags: java, android, imageview, scale

I have the code below and I face a problem with the image view "@+id/logo_skilfull" because it does not keep the aspect.. I think is because of the scaleType or the adjustViewBounds..

[image in tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piypc.png)

[image in a phone (I want this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNreF.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/registration_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="25dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/member_login_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Ingresá tu DNI"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username_edtext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/member_login_tv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/register_uname"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Documento"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/username_edtext"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_access"
                android:text="Aceptar"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_skilfull"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logos"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/member_imview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

> ```
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> ```

This is a problem changing the size of the View.  You need to set scaleType.

Try fitStart.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_skilfull"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logos"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  />
```

Comment: What does not work? You can use the other scaleType: CENTER_CROP etc

Comment: Ahh! Will it work with one of these? I havo to put adjustViewBounds="true"
 AND any scaleType?